# How can I get list of all items present in a particular node?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-groovy

I want to delete few particular job work spaces present in a slave node. For this I would like to fetch all items present in that particular slave, and then delete the workspace of the item that matches the particular job.

For this, I know

*Jenkins.instance.items* gives me a list of all items present in that Jenkins instance (in my case it would be the master node).

whereas

*Jenkins.items* gives me list of all items present in Jenkins.

I need something like,

*node.items* which will give me list of all items present in that particular node,

where node will be one of Jenkins.instance.nodes

My code currently, looks like

```
for (node in Jenkins.instance.nodes) {
    println("node: " + node.getDisplayName())

    if (node.getDisplayName() == 'abc' || node.getDisplayName() == 'def') {
        performCleanup(node, node.items)
    }
}

def performCleanup(def node, def items) {

    for (item in items) {
            workspacePath = node.getWorkspaceFor(item)
            if (workspacePath == null) {
                println(".... could not get workspace path")
                continue
            }

            pathAsString = workspacePath.getRemote()
            if (workspacePath.exists()) {
                workspacePath.deleteRecursive()
                println(".... deleted from location " + pathAsString)
            } else {
                println(".... nothing to delete at " + pathAsString)
            }        
       }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that jenkins nodes do not possess items as such - all the "items", which in your case I believe to be hudson.model.TopLevelItem, exist on master instance, thus nodes do not hold information what they do have. More than that, after looking into https://javadoc.jenkins.io/hudson/model/Node.html#getWorkspaceFor-hudson.model.TopLevelItem- source code, it looks like this method will not help you as well - as if no work space will be found, it will create it, thus instead of deleting you will spam dozens more.

In your case there is another no-brainer available:
If you have particular jobs you want to clear from the particular nodes - just iterate through each node root children - https://javadoc.jenkins.io/hudson/model/Node.html#getRootPath-- and check if folder with job name exists - then clean. That is it, all workspaces should be under root, thus just search by directory name.

Comment: Well, for now I am keeping my question open for more answers then :)